# Javascript: How to prevent time limit reset when refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with the time limit coz when the page is reload/refresh the time limit reset.

P.S: I used this time limit to my online quiz program and I'm using a header location to move to next question.

HTML

```
<label id="time">1:00</label>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        localStorage.setItem('time_remaining_min', minutes);
        localStorage.setItem('time_remaining_sec', seconds);

        var minutes_left = localStorage.getItem('time_remaining_min');
        var seconds_left = localStorage.getItem('time_remaining_sec');

        display.text(minutes_left + ":" + seconds_left);

    if (--timer < 0) {
        //finished
    }
   }, 1000);
 }

 jQuery(function ($) {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = $('#time');
 startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

EDIT:
I tried to use local storage but didn't work

```
        localStorage.setItem('time_remaining_min', minutes);
        localStorage.setItem('time_remaining_sec', seconds);

        var minutes_left = localStorage.getItem('time_remaining_min');
        var seconds_left = localStorage.getItem('time_remaining_sec');

        display.text(minutes_left + ":" + seconds_left);
```

Answer (score 2):

Store timer value either in cookie or in local storage.

Comment: Can u teach me how? I'm sorry i just got the time limit code in SO also. I'm not familiar in storing a value in js in cookie or local storage. In php i'm using $_SESSION[] . thanks

Comment: @VanAdrianCabrera There are good resources for learning about `localStorage`, I would recommend the following from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: `function setTimer(name,display,defvalue) {
var timer = localStorage.getItem('name') || duration,
interval = setInterval(function() {
var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
if (--timer < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        localStorage.removeItem(name);
    }
else {
  localStorage.setItem(name,timer);
   }, 1000);
}


`

Comment: Usage: `jQuery(function ($) {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = $('#time');
 startTimer('myTimer', display,fiveMinutes);
});`

Comment: @VasylMoskalov thanks for the effort i'll try ur code

Comment: @VasylMoskalov I overwrite my code with ur code but i got errors but fixed it but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you will ever be able to get around this with a page refresh.  Maybe the better answer would be to not to the page reload, and use AJAX to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the time in a cookie.

```
//Set cookie
time_remaining = 200;
$.cookie('time_remaining', time_remaining);

//Retrieve cookie
time_remaining = $.cookie('time_remaining');
```

You should be able to easily implement the above into your code (Hint: whenever the timer decreases, save time remaining in a cookie).

Note that this isn't that secure, users can easily clear and modify cookies in their browser. If you're looking for something more secure you'll need to implement some backend functionality.